# tabs.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So, I have an array of tabs in an overflow auto container (the tabs const) and I want to filter them to get the last visible one. My idea is to take the x value of the container (overflowWrapperRight) and get the tab whose left side is less than that value and whose right side is greater than that value. The problem is that I get the message that my filter is not a function. Maybe it´s a silly mistake, but I'm stuck.

```
const overflowWrapperRight =
  wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().x + wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width;
const current = wrapper.scrollLeft;

const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('#tablistPanel .singleTab');

const lastVisibleTab = tabs.filter(
  tab =>
  tab.getBoundingClientRect().left < overflowWrapperRight &&
  tab.getBoundingClientRect().right > overflowWrapperRight
);
```

I should get the single tab which matches that criteria.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, not an Array.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, not an array

Comment: see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

Comment: that means `tabs` has no `filter` prototype. `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList. NodeLists are **iterable** but do **not** have a `filter` prototype, you need to use `[].filter.apply` or spread results to a regular array to work with it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: @JuniusL. Please do not use, recommend or link to w3schools.

Comment: @ChrisG why do you say so?

Comment: @JuniusL. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com (please remove the link as it will boost the site)

Comment: @ChrisG while w3schools may not be the best authority for documentation, their content can be helpful. Regardless, it's not your place to tell people what sources they can recommend.

Comment: @SterlingArcher That's why I said "please"...

Comment: @ChrisG please read the answer on that question.

Comment: Please simply makes your request polite, but the message stays the same.

Comment: Regardless, it's not relevent to the question at all. The comments section of a question isn't the place to push an agenda.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because [`Element#querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) rather than an array.

You can easily convert a nodelist into an array using spreading, like so:

```
const overflowWrapperRight =
  wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().x + wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width;
const current = wrapper.scrollLeft;

const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('#tablistPanel .singleTab');

const lastVisibleTab = [...tabs].filter(
  tab =>
  tab.getBoundingClientRect().left < overflowWrapperRight &&
  tab.getBoundingClientRect().right > overflowWrapperRight
);
```

You could also achieve the same using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility) like so:

```
const lastVisibleTab = Array.from(tabs).filter(
  tab =>
  tab.getBoundingClientRect().left < overflowWrapperRight &&
  tab.getBoundingClientRect().right > overflowWrapperRight
);
```

Finally, there's is the ES5 compatible way using [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) , like so:

```
const lastVisibleTab = Array.prototype.slice.call(tabs).filter(
  tab =>
  tab.getBoundingClientRect().left < overflowWrapperRight &&
  tab.getBoundingClientRect().right > overflowWrapperRight
);
```

Comment: Perfect. I chose Array.from() and it works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @ElDuderino Keep in mind that this will not work for internet explorer, if you want to support IE you should use `Array#slice`